# Different ways of referring to a structure member in C

Tags: c, struct

I have used three different ways, which I think are equivalent, of assigning values to the members of the structures from another function. I am getting the result of **`b`** and **`c`** in the following structure correct but not that of **`a`**. Are these methods of changing the values of the member of the structure not equivalent?

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    typedef struct 
    {
        int a,b,c;
    }
    test_str;
    void change(test_str * my_str_ad);

    int main()
    {
        test_str my_str;
        change(&my_str);
        printf("a: %d, b:%d, c: %d\n", my_str.a, my_str.b, my_str.c);
        return 0;
    }

    void change(test_str * my_str_ad)
    {
        test_str my_str;
        my_str = *my_str_ad;
        my_str.a = 5;
        (*my_str_ad).b  = 6;
        my_str_ad->c = 7;
    }
```

Comment: `my_str = *my_str_ad` is your problem. Its not a pointer and thus it won't change the value of a.

Comment: my_str_ad is address to a structure, I want to dereference the address to get the structure, so that I can access by *str.member* method. Why is this not correct?

Comment: @DurgaDatta you want to use `test_str& my_str;` in your `change` function

Comment: @YuHao  `my_str`  is intended to be of type  `test_str` . Can you please clarify further.

Comment: `my_str.a = 5` won't change the value of `a` in the `my_str` declared in main().

Comment: What is the essential difference between the way I have changed `b` compared to that of `a` ? What would `my_str = * my_str_ad` do in the function `change`?

Comment: It would copy the contents of the struct pointed to by my_str_ad to my_str.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my_str in main() is not same as my_str in change().

As you jump to change() the statement test_str my_str; create a new instance of test_str.
So member 'a' of my_str in main will not be effected by change().

(*my_str_ad).b  = 6;
my_str_ad->c = 7; will work since you are modifying the test_str of main() using the pointer passed to change().

Comment: what does `my_str = *my_str_ad` do in the function ` change` ?

Comment: @DurgaDatta the my_str you declare in `main()`is local to main only and the one you declare in `change()` local to that function only.As already explained in one of the answer the change in `change()` won't reflect in `main()`.

Comment: Now I understand that the change is local, but I still would like to know what is the effect statement in the previous comment of mine.

Answer (score 2):

```
    test_str my_str;
    my_str = *my_str_ad;
    my_str.a = 5;
```

What is happening here is that you are COPYING `my_str_ad`'s target variable into `my_str`. So the changes you make to `my_str` do not affect the `my_str` in your main. This cannot be fixed in C. i.e only your other two methods can be used.

[C++ only]
What you can do to get this to work is to change the first line, as I mentioned, to-

```
  test_str& my_str;
```

Comment: The question both has "C" in the title and is tagged C, too.